# FifoPriorityThreadPoolExecutor in glide v4

Tags: android, android-glide

I am migrating an app to glide v4.7.1 from v3 and have noticed that FifoPriorityThreadPoolExecutor class was removed. We use it to limit number of threads Glide use to do network operations.

Old code

```
public class GlideConfiguration implements GlideModule {
    @Override
    public void applyOptions(Context context, GlideBuilder builder) {
        builder.setResizeService(new FifoPriorityThreadPoolExecutor(1));
    }

...
}
```

New code

```
@GlideModule
public class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {
    private static final String FIFO_SOURCE_EXECUTOR_NAME = "fifo-source";

    @Override
    public void applyOptions(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull GlideBuilder builder) {
        builder.setSourceExecutor(newSourceExecutor(1, FIFO_SOURCE_EXECUTOR_NAME, GlideExecutor.UncaughtThrowableStrategy.DEFAULT));
    }
...

}
```

But it still uses 4 threads. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you checking number of threads running?
I've used same code snippet and its running as expected with only one thread.
Glide uses "glide-" + name + "-thread-" + threadNum format to name threads which will be "glide-fifo-source-thread-0" in your case.

Comment: @abhishesh I use Stetho tool to monitor running network calls and can see that 4 calls are being sent simultaneously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking glide's source code.
Glide will initialize its default source executor only if no source executor has been provided to builder.

```
    Glide build(@NonNull Context context) {
        if (sourceExecutor == null) {
             sourceExecutor = GlideExecutor.newSourceExecutor();
        }

        if (diskCacheExecutor == null) {
            diskCacheExecutor = GlideExecutor.newDiskCacheExecutor();
        }

        if (animationExecutor == null) {
            animationExecutor = GlideExecutor.newAnimationExecutor();
        }
    ...
    }
    // Glide executor is simply a wrapper over ThreadPoolExecutor class.    
    public static GlideExecutor newSourceExecutor(int threadCount, String name, UncaughtThrowableStrategy uncaughtThrowableStrategy) {
        return new GlideExecutor(new ThreadPoolExecutor(threadCount /* corePoolSize */,threadCount /* maximumPoolSize */,0 /* keepAliveTime */,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,new PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable>(),new DefaultThreadFactory(name, uncaughtThrowableStrategy, false)));
    }
```

Since you are inspecting threads using Stetho library to monitor network call which doesn't show any information about threads. It's very likely that these requests are being initiated by single thread.

To better understand thread usage in app, you should inspect it using `Android monitor -> DDMS -> Threads.`

I have checked using DDMS Threads tool and found only one thread running with mentioned code snippet.
[image]

Comment: Hey, thank you! I have checked thread count and with my code it only shows 1 thread with my fixed name, so you are right. However, it still sends 4 network calls simultaneously. Is it possible even with 1 thread?

Comment: Yeah, that's possible with 1 thread. Actually those requests are being sent by same thread. If you run test by simulating very slow network condition(using tools like charles proxy), you'll find they are serially being executed.